# WPF XAML: Border Brush on Button with IsDefault="True"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I try to enter a border brush colour on a button with the IsDefault="True" property, the border will not change and stay with a blue border for the IsDefault Property.

If I remove IsDefault="True", then the border brush colour applies.

Is there a way to have the button as default and also give it a custom border colour?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the button `ControlTemplate`, which changes the button appearance on some occasions.

Have a look at the style / control template of a default button:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The relevant parts are probably the

```
<Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome"
    ...
    RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
    RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
    RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}"
    ... >
```

and the control template triggers

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
</Trigger>
```

So for your specific case, if you really only want a different border for `IsDefault` but you want all the border changing for focus, mouseover and other states, then you can modify the control template by setting `RenderDefaulted="False"` in the `Themes:ButtonChrome` (instead of `RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}"`).

Answer (score 0):

**Method1:** Best way to do this is just define a style in your `Window.Resources` which applies that style to all buttons:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Method 2:**
Another way is to add `x:Key="yourButtonStyle"` to the `Style` element and assign it to any button you want in the `Style` property:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="yourButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource yourButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: You need to remove the `x:Key` in Method 1 if you want the style to be applied to all buttons. The TargetType is always needed !

Comment: No luck :/ Still stayed default blue colour

Comment: @NiallMitch14 yes that's what it is meant to do. You have the default colour of the button - then the ones you want different apply the style to and change the Value to the colour you want

Comment: Yeah I know it's still blue in your example. But I changed the colour to green and it was still blue

Comment: Your button must not be a button type, change x:Type: Button to x:Type ButtonChrome or whatever type you are using

Comment: Nope it is definitely a button :/

Comment: Can you edit you question and put the code from your xaml please, where you declare the button and the style